# SQL query table based on query from alternitive table

Tags: php, mysql

I'm currently trying to return all of the results in a table associated with a specific user (the user is identified using a session variable, this part is working) then take each of those results and pass them into another table and print out the results to the user.

Currently, my system is working, however it is only processing the first result from the original query in the second query instead of each result of the first query.

My current code:

```
<?php
$conn = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "tcom");

if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
$uid = $_SESSION['userID'];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM core_apps_owned WHERE UserID = $uid";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $app = $row["AppID"];
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM core_apps WHERE AppID = $app";
        $result = $conn->query($sql);

        if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

            while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                echo "<li>".$row["icon"]."</li>";
            }
        } else {
            echo "Error Unable to find app $app";
        }
    }
} else {
    echo "No Owned Apps!";
}
$conn->close();
?>
```

I should also mention that my naming is poor as well as my security as I'm connecting through root and maintainability is also poor, however these are all things which will be fixed once I get the system working correctly.

These are my tables:

core_apps_owned:

```
UserID | AppID
-------+-------
  4    |  3
  7    |  9
  4    |  9
  4    |  2
```

core_apps:

```
AppID | name     | icon
------+----------+------
  3   | TestApp3 |   3 
  9   | TestApp9 |   9
```

Comment: You're reusing the variable `$result` for the inner query. Use different variable names.

Comment: Would a MySQL join work better here?

Comment: Yes, as @MatthewPage says, it would be better to join the two queries instead of doing multiple queries.

Comment: `SELECT * FROM core_apps_owned AS o JOIN core_apps AS a ON a.AppID = o.AppID WHERE o.UserID = $uid`

Comment: You might have to add $result->free(); on the end of the first loop, try it and let me know if that worked

Comment: @Barmar 's first solution solved it :) Thanks, I'm not sure why I hadn't noticed that. I'm off to go learn how an SQL join works so I can use it more in the future.

Comment: **Warning:** You are wide open to [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should really use parameterized **prepared statements** instead of manually building your queries. They are provided by [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) or by [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Never trust any kind of input, especially that which comes from the client side. Even when your queries are executed only by trusted users, [you are still in risk of corrupting your data](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're overriding the `$result` variable. Just use a different variable and you should be OK:

```
$app = $row["AppID"];
$sqlApp = "SELECT * FROM core_apps WHERE AppID = $app";
$resultApp = $conn->query($sqlApp);
```

Comment: **Warning:** You are wide open to [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should really use parameterized **prepared statements** instead of manually building your queries. They are provided by [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) or by [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Never trust any kind of input, especially that which comes from the client side. Even when your queries are executed only by trusted users, [you are still in risk of corrupting your data](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Comment: @Dharman I do sanitize my inputs, but like I mentioned, some of my security measures hadn't been implemented at this point.

Answer (score -1):

You have declared a variable with a SQL query and you have to get data from it, in the same boucle you declare a new variable with the same name well the contain of the result in the first will be replaced with the result query in the second query, and this it is not correct, you should use different variable names to save the first result